# Bundling CSS, file size vs. request payload

Tags: css, module, httprequest, bundling-and-minification

I read a lot of blogs that suggest bundling CSS files, like this one: http://www.webpronews.com/want-a-faster-website-reduce-requests-2-2012-03

Then I thought about all the unused styles and the file size.

Is there a generic rule on how to decide between splitting up large CSS files or bundling them to reduce requests?

Example: On one subpage, there is an element which needs a huge pile of CSS rules. Every other page does not use this element. Speaking in kB, how large must this pile of CSS be, to impact loading times for the other pages enough to be worth a second HTTP request just for that one page? Is it possible to say, if the element requires 50kB of data, the benefits of caching and short loading time are big enough to safe a http request for a second CSS file.

If there is a specific size limit, would it be a good idea to automate the process with, for example gulp, to generate "modularized" CSS chunks and include them only where they are needed?

Comment: can't find it right now, but i recall Paul Irish mentioning some stats on this a long while back